# get data into correct format to create an area chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

my json data currently looks like this:

```
var data = {"history":[
        {"date":"2013-10-15","value":15},
        {"date":"2013-11-15","value":5},
        {"date":"2013-12-15","value":5},
        {"date":"2014-01-15","value":8},
        {"date":"2014-02-15","value":5}
    ]}
```

I'm trying to create an area chart like so:

```
svg.selectAll("path.area")
        .data(d3.values(data.history))
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", d3.svg.area()
            .x(function (d) { return xScale(d.date); })
            .y0(height)
            .y1(function (d) { return yScale(d.value); })
        );
```

I can't seem to get the data in the correct format to be interpreted by the area function.

Comment: Have you tried `.data([data.history])`?

Comment: I had not tried this but unfortunately it does not work either. I have a date parsing that is occuring above this:

    data.history.forEach(function (d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.value = +d.value;
        });

I shouldn't have to reparse the dates? My x-axis is displaying the correct date range...

Comment: Could you post the code for that as well please?

Comment: here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/featherita/Yfc6G/

Comment: Actually the only thing that's missing is a `.enter()` after `.data()` and the translation by -600 -- http://jsfiddle.net/Yfc6G/1/

Comment: Well that was a major oversight on my part, ha! I am still glad I asked, setting it up as '.data([])' was also needed. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Example from the d3 [wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting):

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
format.parse("2011-01-01"); // returns a Date
```

You probably just need to parse the date string into a `Date` object using the built-in parser. After defining the `format` variable as above, you would change the line

`.x(function (d) { return xScale(d.date); })`

to read: `.x(function(d){ return xScale(format.parse(d.date)); })`

You may also need to change your `xScale()` function accordingly, see the [wiki page about d3 Time Scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales) for info about how to do that.

Comment: I'm already parsing the date in a previous function. I should have published the whole picture, my x axis is working great and i am rendering dots for these same values, I just can't get the area chart to understand the data that I'm giving it.